# Consuming PHP wsdp soap server with Java client server

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap

I've made a Java client server that consume the PHP wsdl soap server and it's succesfully communicate, but i can't get the response (the response value is null). And when i try to check the request and response it surely response something. Is it something wrong with my java code or the server ?

This is my client java code:

```
package siclient;

import wsdlquery.*;

public class SIClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {                      
        WsdlQueryRequest request = new WsdlQueryRequest();        
        request.setToken("ABCDEFGHIJ");       

        ArryQueryRequest array = new ArryQueryRequest();
        array.setParam1("W1113OK");     
        array.setParam2("20151001");
        array.setParam3("20151001");              
        request.getAddItemsRequest().add(array);                                             

        WsdlQueryResponse respond = send(request);            
        System.out.println("Result : " + respond);
    }

    private static WsdlQueryResponse send(WsdlQueryRequest wsdlQueryRequest) {
        WsdlQuery service = new WsdlQuery();
        WsdlQueryPortType port = service.getWsdlQueryPort();
        return port.gps(wsdlQueryRequest);
    }
```

This is the result

```
Result : null
```

And this is the request and response i get when i run it

```
---[HTTP request - https://website.com:443/xxxxx.php]---
Accept: [text/xml, multipart/related]
Content-Type: [text/xml; charset=utf-8]
SOAPAction: ["urn:wsdlQuery#gps"]
User-Agent: [JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01]
<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:gps xmlns:ns2="urn:wsdlQuery"><wsdlQueryRequest><token>7H1S3FY7U2</token><addItemsRequest><param1>H4444HH</param1><param2>20151001</param2><param3>20151027</param3></addItemsRequest></wsdlQueryRequest></ns2:gps></S:Body></S:Envelope>--------------------
---[HTTP response - https://website.com:443/xxxxx.php - 200]---
null: [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Connection: [Keep-Alive]
Content-Length: [539]
Content-Type: [text/xml; charset=UTF-8]
Date: [Sun, 06 Mar 2016 11:53:21 GMT]
Keep-Alive: [timeout=5, max=100]
Server: [Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8k PHP/5.2.9 mod_apreq2-20051231/2.6.0 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0]
X-Powered-By: [PHP/5.2.9]
X-SOAP-Server: [NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><gpsResponse xmlns="urn:wsdlQuery"><wsdlQueryResponse><ResponseCode>01</ResponseCode><ResponseMessage>Response value was here</ResponseMessage></wsdlQueryResponse></gpsResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>--------------------
```

Then i try to mak a client with with php and this the code

```
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$token='7H1S3FY7U2';
$wsdl='https://website.com/xxxxx.php?wsdl';
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl,true);
$err = $client->getError();

if ($err){
    echo '<h2>Constructor Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
}else{
    $param['wsdlQueryRequest'] = array('token'=>$token,
                                       'addItemRequest'=>array(
                                            array(
                                                'param1'=>'W1113OK',
                                                'param2'=>'20150101',
                                                'param3'=>'20151001'
                                                ),
                                        )
                                );
    $result = $client->call('gps', $param);
    print_r($result);
}
?>
```

Result of php code is like this

```
Array ( [ResponseCode] => 01 [ResponseMessage] => Response value was here )
```

Comment: Is there anyone that might the same problem ? Any question or answer will be appreciated . .

Comment: i try several method and i got respond when i use httpconnection this is the result i get --> 
null<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope ... etc

why there is null in front of xml declaration ?